# Edições Inúteis

Tags: suporte, edição

Me deparo constantemente principalmente aqui no stackoverflow em português, alguns usuários que fazem edições inúteis. Como isso deve ser tratado? Visto que tais usuários não precisam passar por uma revisão.

Um exemplo é nesta pergunta: [Ajuda com query](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/282876/revisions)

Onde um usuário novo criou uma pergunta com uma query sem o formato específico de código, acarretando na falta de informação.

Uma primeira edição foi feita para corrigir esse problema, mas em seguida outro usuário fez mais uma edição, substituindo: "no Sql SERVER" por "em SQL Server", "Ele me retorna..." por "Me retorna..." e "... 4 valores..." por "... quatro valores..." sendo que existem mais situações no texto em que o númeral 4 aparece no mesmo sentido do anterior e não foi editado.

Tendo isso em vista, imagino que foi uma edição apenas por reputação, e não uma edição para fins de melhorar a pergunta e ajudar o companheiro.

Existe uma forma de reportar tal comportamento? O que é possível se fazer?

Comment: Apenas para facilitar editei sua pergunta colocando o link das revisões

Comment: Opa. Obrigado. :)

Comment: Não conheço mecanismo para sinalizar edições. No caso, o revisor realmente tirou marcas estilísticas do autor que poderiam ter erros gramaticais por marcas estilísticas do revisor com erros gramaticais também. Isso é errado e deve ser combatido. O como eu não sei, não lembro. Corrigir alguns enganos morfossintáticos é bem vindo, mas mudar a estilística usada pelo autor no texto não.

Comment: Já tive casa de esta analisando uma edição vi que a edição era inútil, mas o AP aceitou a edição antes de eu finalizar a analise :)

Comment: Pra mim foi uma edição descartável, de fato, mas nada de tão grave para reportar moderação ou que caiba um rollback. É apenas uma questão de entendimento pessoal meu sobre quando edições são úteis ou não. Eu não aprovaria se visse na fila, mas como disse, não é nada de tão grave o fato de ter sido feita.

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado pelo feedback :)

Comment: Se vc achar inútil a revisão vc pode nega-la dizendo que "Não apresenta Melhorias", mas se vc não tiver esse privilégio ainda, vc pode entrar na lista de edições e clicar em "Reverter" assim ela volta para última versão antes da Edição.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você acha que uma edição foi maliciosa, você pode ir na pergunte e sinalizar. Escolha *"precisa de atenção dos moderadores"*. Uma caixa de texto aparecerá, onde você deve descrever o que acha que está errado com a pergunta (nesse caso, edições "inúteis").

Note, porém, que usuários com mais de 2.000 pontos de reputação não ganham pontos por edições. Logo, está errada a sua premissa de que esse foi o caso na pergunta que você mencionou.

Também creio ser errada a premissa de que [a edição discutida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/282876/revisions) foi inútil. Eu converso com pessoas do Brasil, de Portugal, de Angola e de Cabo Verde, e em nenhum desses locais se fala *"estou com um problema em SQL Server"*. Isso me parece algo que viria de uma tradução de máquina, ou um sinal de que o OP não tem português como primeira língua. Mas sei lá, vai que é assim que se fala em São Tomé ou Guiné-Bissau...

Já sobre passar "quatro" para a forma por extenso, para mim é algo que torna o texto mais legível. É uma questão de estilo apenas. Por não mudar o texto nem se converter em premiação gratuita ao editor, não vejo problema com isso.

Comment: Com relação ao usáurio ter mais de 2.000 pontos e não poder mais receber pontução por edição, não é possível ter tanta certeza. Visto que a pontuação por edição no stackoverflow é +2 por edição e com um máximo de +1.000 por usuário. Não quer dizer que quem tem acima de 1.000 não receba mais, apenas quem já recebeu +1.000 vindo de edições .

Comment: @DavidAlves acima de 2000 não recebe +2.

Comment: Entendido. Obrigado pelo feedback :)

Comment: `Com relação ao usáurio ter mais de 2.000 pontos e não poder mais receber pontução por edição, não é possível ter tanta certeza.` [Você ganha dois pontos por edição sugerida.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Ocorre que [a partir de 2.000 pontos suas edições não são mais sugestões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Eu sei que em qualquer lugar é pedir demais que as pessoas leiam e entendam todo o manual, mas quando a informação vem de alguém que participa há anos do site, você deve ao menos considerar se não há ao menos uma chance de verdade nela.

Comment: Apenas um aparte: Eu, neste contexto, usaria "estou com um problema **em** SQL Server" já que estaria a referir-me ao SQL como "linguagem". Caso me referisse ao banco/motor então usaria **no**.

Comment: @ramaral concordo com a gramática, porém SQL Server é o sistema servidor... A linguagem em si é apenas SQL, ou T-SQL a depender do caso.

Comment: Há casos(não digo que seja este) que há necessidade de referir o motor. Cada motor tem particularidades no SQL que usa. Concordo que será mais adequado usar T-SQL do que SQL Server neste contexto. Não quero gerar discussão. Apenas digo que, mantendo a frase como está, é "mais correcto" usar *em* do que *no*.